# How to change Core Data database: baby steps?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, core-data, database-migration

I've a LIVE app and I want to change the core data database.

I've be dealing with the migration errors and reading the several questions and answers, but I'd like to ask the following:

What are the correct sequence steps to do this change?

In my case I just want to add attributes to a single table, but from where do I start and what are the several steps?
For example, I start by creating a new version of the xcdatamodel?
Add the attributes and create new .h and .m files or replace the existing?
Do I need to fill Identifier on Core Data Model (the current model is not filled)?

Thanks a lot.
Regards,
hp

Comment: Have you read the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it fails to answer basic questions for a real change situation, like do I need to change the Type from "Default - Core Data Model" to whatever? I'm reading and doing trial and error, but this site fortunately enables to speed up the process if someone has been there and is willing to share...

Comment: No, you don't need to change that, which is why the guide doesn't mention doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me (adapted from Pro Core Data for iOS, Apress). And this assumes that you are only adding attributes to a table. The migration steps are not appropriate for some more complex model changes.

Prepare your new model...

1. Select your data model in the project navigator.
2. Select Add Model Version from the Editor menu.
3. Accept or change the Version name (I like to take out the space) and click Finish. Now the original model expands to show 2 models. One is the original and it has a green checkmark because it's still the one being used.
4. Select the new model.
5. Make your changes.
6. In the Utilities pane show the file inspector view. Look down for the Model Version section and set Current to the new model you created. You'll see in the project navigator that your new model now has the green checkmark.

Migrate...

You need to tell Xcode to automatically handle this migration, which it can do as long as the migration fits within what's called a lightweight migration which yours does.

1. In Xcode search for "addpersistentstorewithtype". If you created the app from a template and/or you have a standard core data stack implementation it's going to be in your app delegate in the persistentStoreCoordinator method.
2. Add an options NSDictionary between the declaration of storeURL and error...

like this...

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataTest.sqlite"];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

NSError *error = nil;
```

Then in the call to `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:` for the options parameter replace nil with options like this...

```
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                               configuration:nil
                                                         URL:storeURL
                                                     options:options
                                                       error:&error])
```

The last step is to update any affected NSManagedObect subclasses, if you have them. If the changes to the model are small it may be easier to simply edit the files directly. Or you may choose to regenerate the files (select the entity, then from the Editor menu select CreateNSManagedObject subclass...) If you have added your own code in either the .h or .m you'll need to make sure you save those files somewhere first like the Desktop, regenerate the files, and then carefully copy your code into the newly generated files.

Build and run.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! After the first comment I went for more google digging and I found this "old" link (https://joshjustice.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/adding-an-attribute-to-a-core-data-entity-in-xcode-4/) that also has these steps - it only additionally includes the NSManagedObject classes generation. Thanks again, Murray!

Comment: @HugoPereira Right. I've now included the NSManagedObject subclass step.